# Mockito:How to mock method called inside another method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am new to mockito and I am using mockito to test method which is calling another method and called method returns string.
I tried but I am unable write test. Please help

```
public class MyClass {
  protected String processIncominData(String input) {
    String request = ...;
    ...
    String response = forwardRequest(request);
    ...
    return response;
  }

  public String forwardRequest(String requestToSocket) {
   String hostname = socketServerName;
    int port = socketServerPort;
    String responseLine=null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;  
    PrintStream outs=null;

    BufferedReader is = null;
    BufferedWriter bwriter=null;

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        outs=new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        bwriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Don't know about host: " + hostname + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: " + hostname + e.getMessage());
    }

    if (clientSocket == null || outs == null || is == null) {
        LOGGER.error("Something is wrong. One variable is null.");
    }
    try {
        while ( true ) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(requestToSocket);

            String  request = sb.toString().trim();
            bwriter.write(request);
            bwriter.write("\r\n");
            bwriter.flush();
            responseLine = is.readLine();
            LOGGER.info("Socket returns : " + responseLine);
            //outs.println(responseLine);
            bwriter.close();
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Trying to connect to unknown host: "+ e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException:  "+ e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        try {
            outs.close();
            is.close();
            clientSocket.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return responseLine;
  }
}
```

I want to mock xml response here to test processIncomingData method..This response is coming from socket server and I am sending request by socket client. I think socket will not matter if I can mock xmlResponse from socket. Please give any helpful answer

Comment: Show how `xmlResponse` is being generated. You need to use a mock at the line `String xmlResponse = ...;`. If this is an instance method call, use `Mockito` to mock the bean (read socket client). If this is a static call, use `JMockit` to mock the static call.

Comment: I am reading xml response from socket server. It is in string format like "<response><test>123</test></response>" etc

Comment: Your unit test should not depend on a socket server. You should be mocking the client.

Comment: can you please tell how to mock client?

Comment: Post more code. Specifically, 1) the full line of code that retrieves `xmlResponse` 2) how `MyClass` gets the instance of the client it is using.

Comment: I have posted code please see in question asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have posted it, the answer to how to mock it is here.

[testing-java-sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577274/testing-java-sockets)

Comment: but I am not using socket in my first method?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the `spy` method:

```
MyClass myClass = spy(new MyClass());
when(myClass.forwardRequest("foo")).thenReturn("bar");
```

then when you call

```
myClass.processIncominData("baz");
```

the response will be "bar" (if request is "foo")

PS: When you need to mock class under test it shows some problem with your design.

Comment: But better refactor this to have thous methods in different classes.

Comment: Generally considered bad practice to mock the class under test.

Comment: @JohnB Yes. It is wy I'm added comment to separate class.

Comment: Didn't realize that was a comment on your own post. Might have been better to edit your post to put the expansion in the body.

Comment: @JohnB It was not part of answer, just general hint. But I  edited my answer.

Comment: Yes I agree It should be in different class but I have some limitations...@talex but code you have given is not working

Comment: OR please Let me know how to do it when second method is in different class?

Comment: @Lakshya not working? Real method is executed? Check parameter or replace it to `anyString()`

Comment: no not working with anyString too..it breaks at when().thenReturn

Comment: I got it it was because of input steam..I mocket it and its working now..thank you

Comment: In my case I have to use `do...()` functions, like `doReturn("bar").when(myClass).forwardRequest("foo")` to prevent actual implementation of `forwardRequest()` being run when defining the mock